# What is this ridge inside my toilet flange? Do I need to replace it?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, flange

Does this toilet flange need to be replaced? There is a weird gap within the pipe and I can't tell if its because the flange needs replacement or normal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "weird gap"? I don't see anything strange about that flange, except that it's below the surrounding floor

Comment: Maybe its hard to tell from the picture, but looking inside the flange/pipe, there is a ridge of some kind a couple inches down. I can't tell if the inside portion is the pvc pipe and the outside is the flange that's attached to the outside of it or if its something else.

Comment: A couple inches? So you're not just referring to the top of the pipe? Please post a properly focused photo.

Comment: Is it me or does it appear that the flange is mounted 90 degrees sideways, the slotted flange bolts opening are in the front and back instead of the sides. ( based on the caulking  pattern. )

Comment: I think you're right.  It looks like the original installer used the wrong slot openings for the toilet bolts.  Guessing from the pink stains, it's probably glued in incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a standard toilet flange, but it's attached to a 3" pipe instead of a 4" (that's what the 4x3 on top means). It could also be [a "push fit" flange](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L467F82) that you push into the drain pipe to replace an older flange. I admit this looks weird, because I would expect the inside lip to be sloped downward so sewage can't sit on top.

The flange itself is low, but appears to be in good shape. I wouldn't replace it just because of the lip. It looks like that's standard to all the Charlotte 4x3 flanges I've seen.